# Android different styles on API 27

Tags: android

Different styles and strings are defined for the app. On Android prior to 8 everything is OK, but on Android 8 styles are not loaded correctly.

Note: strings are fine. Its just styles.

```
res
    values
        styles.xml
        strings.xml
    values-fr
        styles.xml
        strings.xml
    values-v21
        styles.xml
```

I changed the app locale like this:

```
public static Context changeAppLocale(String lang, Context c) {

        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources resources = c.getResources();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(resources.getConfiguration());
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 24){
            LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
            LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
            config.setLocale(locale);
            config.setLocales(localeList);
            c = c.createConfigurationContext(config);
        }
        else{
            config.locale = locale;
            resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return c;
    }
```

And I apply it inside the activity like this:

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    context = G.changeAppLocale(G.appLang, newBase);
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
}
```

Once again, strings are loaded correctly, but styles not (Just on Android 8).
Are different styles not supported on Android anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in case somebody has the same problem and it may help them.

I was inflating the layout dynamically and I was using a static inflater that was instantiated by an old context.

```
// in class extended from Application

public static LayoutInflater globalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

And when I was inflating:

```
...
    pageView = (ViewGroup) G.globalInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main_log, container, false);
...
```

But that inflater was not updated when I was changing the app locale. Thus views would be inflated from an old locale. Now I instantiate the inflater every time I want to inflate a view:

```
 ...
Context context = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
if(inflater != null){
    pageView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main_log, container, false);
}
    ...
```

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android supports different styles. If I'm not mistaken your issue is with your resources directories declaration. You are missing the following directory:

```
values-fr-v21
```

If you want a customization per `Locale` and `API` you need to define it. By default, the values directory without localization is used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there aren't any overlapping styles between values-v21 and values-fr. They don't have any conflicts. And it works fine on api 21 to 25. It's just api 26

Comment: By the way I just gave it a try and no luck :(

Comment: If you don't apply the changeAppLocale, are the styles applied correctly?

Comment: No, because that method will never be called. Or if I call it once and don't use 'attachBaseContext' then it will not work on higher APIs (like Android 6)